# Coordination of Quarkus application with multiple instances

Tags: java, kubernetes, cloud, quarkus

Is there a (standard) way multiple instances of a Quarkus application can be coordinated?

A possible use case is the scheduler. When scheduling a periodic task to run every 10 seconds it should do regardless of the number of instances in the cluster.

Comment: you mean like a [scheduler](https://quarkus.io/guides/scheduled-guide)? Or do you need the timer to be cluster-ready? Then [quarkus/QuartsScheduler](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/extensions/scheduler/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/scheduler/runtime/QuartzScheduler.java) could be a way to go.

Comment: The scheduler is just an example problem that might need coordination between instances. Another is caching data locally and sending invalidation messages to other instances in the cluster.

Comment: For the caching, I would fall-back on a distributed cache, e.g. [Redis](https://redis.io) or [memcached](https://memcached.org). Getting caching right is a hard problem and I would not trust a self-coded solution for this.

Comment: For k8s cluster coordination, I think you can use [Quarkus Kubernetes client](https://quarkus.io/guides/kubernetes-client) for a cross cluster scheduler, maybe use an external tool like [Chronos](https://medium.com/airbnb-engineering/chronos-a-replacement-for-cron-f05d7d986a9d)